# What's the best way to go about form validation in WPF (with databinding)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation, data-binding

I have several forms with many textboxes/comboboxes, and I would like to have the "Save" button disabled while at least one of the fields are invalid. I've been able to setup some custom ValidationRules, like so (textbox example shown):

```
<Binding Path="Name">
    <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <my:TextFieldNotEmpty/>
    </Binding.ValidationRules>
</Binding>
```

My question is: how can I set my form up so that, when even 1 validation rule fails, the "Save" button is not enabled? Is there a standard way of handling a situation (a trigger, perhaps), or is this a place where WPF falls short?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting WPF Validation Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127477/detecting-wpf-validation-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this answer your question?  [Detecting WPF Validation Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127477/detecting-wpf-validation-errors)

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It shows how to use validation in WPF and how to control the Save button when validation errors exists.

Comment: this app is great. it will increase the quality of my code ! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at SignumFramework ErrorSummary class:

http://www.signumframework.com/EntityControls.ashx#ErrorSummary
http://signum.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/25903#510524