# WPF Validation Errors

Tags: wpf, validation, data-binding, validationrule

In my current projet, I have to deal with data validation in a WPF form. My form is in a DataTemplate in a ResourceDictionnary. I can save and load the data from my form thanks to two buttons, which serialize and deserialize the data (through two [DelegateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431410%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)).

If one field of my form is empty or invalid, the save button is disable. A field is checked everytime it changes thanks to the UpdateSourceTrigger propertie. That's why I need to know in my C# code if a field is invalid to update my save command.

Currently, I use the ExceptionValidationRule in my XAML Binding and I wonder if it's a good pratice. I can't implement a ValidationRule because I need to know in my C# code if a field is invalid, to update the save command (enable or disable the save button).

```
<TextBox>
    <Binding Path="Contact.FirstName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <ExceptionValidationRule/>
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</TextBox>
```

In this [blog](http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/Data-Validation-in-WPF.aspx), we can read :

> Raising exceptions in the Setters is not a very good approach since those properties are also set by code and sometimes it is ok to temporarily leave them with error values.

I already read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127477/detecting-wpf-validation-errors) but I can't use it, my TextBox are in a DataTemplate and I can't use them in my C# code.

So, I wonder if I should change my Data Validation and don't use the ExceptionValidationRule.

Comment: did you try IDataErrorInfo and MVVM ?

Comment: Yeah I already use MVVM. IDataErrorInfo seems to be a good solution... Would it be better than ExceptionValidationRule ?

Comment: i would say yes, but its also had its drawbacks. especially if you have properties with a type other then string in your vw. we use idataerrorinfo in our projects and it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you [blindmeis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355239/blindmeis), your idea was good.
IDataErrorInfo seems to be better than the ExceptionValidationException and it works.

Here is an example which match my project :
[IDataErrorInfo sample](http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/06/wpf-textbox-validation-idataerrorinfo.html#.UTSeqFevwZ0)

It doesn't use the DelegateCommand but is simple enough to be modified. Your model has to implement IDataErrorInfo :

```
public class Contact : IDataErrorInfo
{

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string this[string property]
    {
        get 
        {
            string result = null;
            if (property== "Name")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) || Name.Length < 3)
                    result = "Please enter a Name";
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

}
```

In the XAML code, don't forget to change the Binding :

```
<TextBox>
    <Binding Path="Contact.Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True"/>
</TextBox>
```