# WPF highlighting tab headers where validation fails

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, tabcontrol

I currently have a tab control containing multiple tab items, where each tab item contains different custom user control. **I would like the tab headers to turn red when the associated tab contains a validation failure**. My validations are implemented as ValidationRules on the appropriate bindings (moving to IDataError or another validation approach is not a feasible solution). Each tab specific control tracks it's errors through the bubbling ValidationErrorsEvent and exposes a count.

I am currently using x:Name on the tab specific controls & ElementName in the TabItem headers to bind the count exposed by the tab specific controls to the color of the text in the header (via a converter).

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Tab 1" Foreground="{Binding Errors.Count, ElementName=_tabOne, Converter={StaticResource ErrorCountToColorConverter}}" />
        </TabItem.Header>
        <AdornerDecorator>
            <my:CustomTabOneControl x:Name="_tabOne" />
        </AdornerDecorator>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Tab 2" Foreground="{Binding Errors.Count, ElementName=_tabTwo, Converter={StaticResource ErrorCountToColorConverter}}" />
        </TabItem.Header>
        <AdornerDecorator>
            <my:CustomTabTwoControl x:Name="_tabTwo" />
        </AdornerDecorator>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Due to the lazyness of WPFs tab control, the validation of each tab does not occur until it is opened. As such the headers for tabs containing invalid fields do not turn red until the tab has been opened (after that they remain correct).

Can anyone suggest a way of resolving this issue, or an alternative approach to achieve the same tab highlighting?

Comment: Hi Phil, take a look at this link, I think its something similar to what you want; http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97564/Attributes-based-Validation-in-a-WPF-MVVM-Applicat. But rather then the text of the tab name changing colour, it changes an image based on the attributes that have validation. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi Gregory, thanks for your input, unfortunately the linked article makes use of IDataError (viewmodel side) validation tracking (mine is view side), which as I say in my original post, is not a feasible solution in my circumstance.

Comment: You should take a look at the `xaml` in particular though. It uses datatriggers and styles to enable the change of the `tab control` header, which I thought might be appropriate to you for you to try and implement.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this post and answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/52baa60e-f718-48e8-9a9a-ad4aeff6247a); it is a lot of work and possibly maintenance but it does work by using a multitrigger that sets the header template based on the HasError property of the controls. Unfortunately it requires you to add a condition to the trigger for each control that should influence the state of the header.

You could try combine this with the answer to this post: [Detecting WPF Validation Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127477/detecting-wpf-validation-errors)

that walks the visual tree to find Validation Errors. Thereby making it dynamic and less dependent on maintaining the trigger conditions when building the UI.