# Check validation errors for all bindings bound to current DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a form with some controls (say TextBox) which Text property is bound to some DataContext (say DataRowView).

I want to know if this row was filled correctly without any validation errors. [I have found one possible solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127477/detecting-wpf-validation-errors) But I do not like it. It is not good to enum all the DependencyObjects on a form. Is there any way to enum only those DependencyObjects which was bound to this DataContext? May be some magic with BindingOperations...

Answer (score 0):

How do you validate the input-data?

Maybe you could use a BindingGroup and then check it's Validation.HasError attached property.