# What event raises if there is a validation error?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have a textbox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeInt}" />
```

SomeInt is of type `int` and therefore when my view shows, if binded correctly it displays the value of SomeInt in my case 0.

If I enter "abc" on the textbox then the textbox shows a red border outside of it which is great. **How can I detect that the textbox has a red border in order to prevent the user from submitting the form?**.

Comment: FYI This is a *validation* error, not a binding one. Binding errors throw `System.Data` (some class I don't remember) exceptions. IIRC its OnDataError or something like that for validation errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting WPF Validation Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127477/detecting-wpf-validation-errors)

Comment: In MVVM you'd be doing validation in the VM and implement IDEI.  In this case, I'd use a nullable int and report an error if the value was null.