# Checking validation for the whole User control fields

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have a User Control inside Window which fires validation when a user interacts with that.
in code behind of window i check validation result such as :

```
private void CheckValidationResults(){

if (Validation.GetHasError(MyUserControl.NameTextBox) ||
    Validation.GetHasError(MyUserControl.FamilyTextBox) ||
    Validation.GetHasError(MyUserControl.AgeTextBox)) return;    
else    
 //  do something if every field is valid
```

> now my question !!
>
> how can i replace it with something like this :

```
private void CheckValidationResults(){

if (Validation.GetHasError(MyUserControl.Fields)) return;
else
 //  do something if every field is valid
```

Comment: Check this and re-try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127477/detecting-wpf-validation-errors

Comment: @Gopu_Tunas It was very good ,thank you.