# WPF RaisePropertyChanged event on lost focus

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a C# WPF MVVM application that works fine.

The only problem is when I modify a textbox and click on the menu. If I do that without clicking on another control, the view->viewmodel event is never fired because the textbox hasn't lost focus. Correct me if I am wrong, but I think the RaisePropertyChanged is only fired on LostFocus (or OnBlur, or any similar event).

So, clicking on the menu save button right after editing the textbox causes the viewmodel to save the data using old values.

So, resuming:

This sequence works fine:

1. Edit the text box
2. Click on another control
3. RaisePropertyChanged is fired, the viewmodel is updated
4. Click on save button on the menu
5. Data Saved with correct values

This sequence gives me an error:

1. Edit the text box
2. Click on save button on the menu
3. Data Saved with correct values

How to solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a common gotcha with TextBoxes in both WPF and WinForms. You can get around this by instructing the binding system to update the VM with every change to the TextBox instead of when it loses focus. To do this, set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` of the binding to `PropertyChanged`. This will write back to the VM any time the TextBox raises the `PropertyChanged` event for its `Text` property.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Answer (score 8):

For the `TextBox.Text` dependency property, its default [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) is `LostFocus` (ie, your view model property gets updated when the control loses focus).  To make the property update immediately whenever text is entered, set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.  (See the link above for more info -- it actually covers your example specifically.)