# Why a TextBox does not lose the focus when acting over a menu in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

if I edit the text on a TextBox that is binded with the ViewModel and then I click at the main application menu (to save the data) the ViewModel does not get updated with the new data because somehow the TextBox does not loose the focus and then the data is not updated. Why the TextBox does not lose the focus and how should I fix that?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57493/wpf-databind-before-saving

Comment: would you provide some code ? anything strange in the debug output ?

Comment: Its a duplicated, I agree. The question was asked in a different way I didn't realize that it was already done.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is databinding updation and not the focus use UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" in the textbox binding.